# How to handle/dispose old NSTrackingAreas in TableCellViews?

Tags: swift, mouseover, nstableview

I have a view-based NSTableView with a NSTrackerArea in each row. The NSTableView contains a list of users, and it updates as users joins and leaves. This is how I make a new cell:

```
        let cell = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "username",
        owner: self) as! NSTableCellView

        let aera = NSTrackingArea.init(rect: cell.bounds, options [
        NSTrackingAreaOptions.activeInKeyWindow,
        NSTrackingAreaOptions.inVisibleRect,
        NSTrackingAreaOptions.mouseEnteredAndExited],
        owner: self, userInfo: nil)

        cell.textField?.stringValue = name
        cell.addTrackingArea(aera)
        return cell
```

The tracking area works, but it this implementation creates multiple layers of tracking areas.

Example: There's 10 users in the chatroom, and user 2 leaves. A new user joins, and gets a row in the tableview. But now this ViewCell has two trackers, overlapping each other. This creates some problems.

And even worse, when I use .reloadData(), a new tracker is created for all rows. I have tried to use .updateTrackingAreas() and to subclass NSTableCellView to remove the tracker at deinit, but niether works. I have also tried to create trackers for each row, instead of doing it directly in the cell, but I did not have the skill to pull it off.

Do you have any ideas? and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using one tracking area per cell, then what you can do is to make sure that you're only adding the tracking area when there is no existing tracking area. You can do so by checking your `cell.trackingAreas` array to see if it is empty. In code, it should look like this:

```
let cell = NSTableCellView.init()

if cell.trackingAreas.count == 0 {
    let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea.init(rect: cell.bounds, options: [.activeInKeyWindow, .inVisibleRect, .mouseEnteredAndExited], owner: self, userInfo: nil)

    cell.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
}

cell.textField.stringValue = name

return cell
```